# oracle apex query sql injection

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i have check my sql query which is vulnerable to sql injection.
V_NAME is detected sql injection.
how can I securing my query ?

this is my query :

```
FUNCTION  "GET_SEQUENCE" (P_BID VARCHAR2, P_PSC VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS
TYPE T_HASIL IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
V_HASIL T_HASIL;
V_NAME VARCHAR2(30);
V_SQL LONG;
BEGIN
SELECT KEYSEQ INTO V_NAME
FROM MST_SEQUENCE_DETAIL Tbl
WHERE BRANCHCODE=P_BID AND KEYCODE=P_PSC
AND YEAR = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'RRRR');

V_SQL := 'SELECT ' || V_NAME || '.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL BULK COLLECT INTO V_HASIL;

RETURN V_HASIL(1);
END;
```

thank u.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using a PL/SQL array, doing a bulk collect, to get only 1 record? You could use a simple numeric value to get the sequence value, you don't need an array.

Comment: By the way, this is not a great way of getting sequence values - part of the point of using Oracle sequences is their excellent performance; using a function like this, presumably being called for *each record before it is inserted*, would perform very poorly.

Comment: thanks u very much... im newbie.

Comment: You have marked MT0's answer as "correct", and while their answer does contain accurate and useful information, it does not fully answer your question as stated, which is *"how to secure my query"*. I don't care about the points but I do care that this Q&A may help future developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Consider if someone performs this insert:

```
INSERT INTO MST_SEQUENCE_DETAIL (
  BRANCHCODE,
  KEYCODE,
  YEAR,
  KEYSEQ
) VALUES (
  1,
  1,
  TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'RRRR' ),
  '(SELECT psswd FROM usr),keyseq'
);
```

Then calling your function:

```
GET_SEQUENCE( 1, 1 );
```

Will set the query to:

```
V_SQL := 'SELECT (SELECT psswd FROM usr),keyseq.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
```

The next statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL BULK COLLECT INTO V_HASIL;
```

Will fail but **how** it fails can tell you whether:

- There is a `usr` table; if is there is not then you will get the exception ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4d95a/4)):

  ```
  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512: at "USER_4_C4D95A.GET_SEQUENCE", line 18
  ```
- It has a column called `psswd`; if there is not then you will get the exception ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b4c87/3))

  ```
  ORA-00904: "PSSWD": invalid identifier ORA-06512: at "USER_4_9B4C87.GET_SEQUENCE", line 18
  ```

Performing this repeatedly, you can start to map the structure of the database and look for other vulnerabilities that may allow greater exploits.

Answer (score 1):

```
V_SQL := 'SELECT ' || V_NAME || '.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL BULK COLLECT INTO V_HASIL;
```

The issue here is that `V_NAME` could in theory be any SQL code and thus an injection vulnerability. The way you protect this is to use `dbms_assert.simple_sql_name`, since you expect this variable to be a simple identifier:

```
V_SQL := 'SELECT ' || sys.dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(V_NAME) || '.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL BULK COLLECT INTO V_HASIL;
```

Comment: The function is vulnerable to SQL Injection.